# virtual function not accessible in derived class

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, overriding, virtual-inheritance

The following code would not compile. GCC complains no matching function for call to ‘derived::print(std::__cxx11::string&).

```
class base
{
public:
    virtual void print(float x){}
    virtual void print(std::string str){}
};

template<class ProcessType>
class CProcess : public base
{
public:
    CProcess(ProcessType* process): m_Storage(process){}
    void print(float x) override{m_Storage->print(x);}
    void print(std::string str) override{m_Storage->print(str);}
private:
    ProcessType* m_Storage;
};

class derived: public base
{
public:
    void print(float x) override{}
    //void print(std::string str) override{}
};

base* ptr = new CProcess<derived>(new derived);
ptr->print(1.0f);
```

Class derived inherits `print(std::string str)` from base so why this error? Now if I also comment `void print(float x) override{}` in derived the compiler does not complain.

The final aim is to implement new behavior for `print(float x)` in derived but keeping the behavior of `print(std::string str)` from base.

I stripped down the production code to the smallest possible version to reproduce the issue so do not recommend smart pointers etc as they are in production code.

Comment: Do you use virtual inheritance here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem isn't caused by it being `virtual`. Since `derived` defines its own `print`, it shadows every *inherited* overload of `print`.

The solution is to add `using base::print;` to the `derived`. Make sure this line is `public`, otherwise the inherited overloads won't be `public`.

Comment: Now if I want to force the users of derived not be able to use the overload `print(std::string str)`. How would I go about it? I tried =delete but it won't work.

Comment: @nae9on But that's already what your code does, no? `print(string)` doesn't work.

Comment: The code now would not even compile :). After adding `using base::print;`, as you suggested the code compiles but it also allows calling the `print(string)` overload which I want should not be possible for some derived classes.

Comment: @nae9on What do you mean? Your code doesn't compile because it does calls the `print(string)` overload, which you say you don't want to be callable. I don't see a problem.

Comment: I understand what you mean, I thought that it would call that overload only if I had something like `ptr->print("Hello");` but in-fact both the overloads are called in class `CProcess`. What I wanted was for `derived` only overload1 was callable and for another `derived2` only overload2 was callable. But I guess that is not possible.

Comment: @nae9on There are several things you could do. `CProcess` could do `static_cast<base *>(m_Storage)->print(...)` instead of `m_Storage->print(...)` (of course it requires the template parameter to always inherit from `base`). Then `CProcess` will be able to call all the `base` methods, even the shadowed ones (so you no longer need `using base::print;`).